# Moving/sliding a table row with Jquery

Tags: jquery, move

I am trying to create a scenario where I click a table row, and the row moves so content can be displayed based on that row clicked.

Right now I am just trying to get the table row to move smoothly on a toggle, (or move at all to start), but it isn't doing anything.

Here is my code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#tableRowID').click(function() {
    $('#tableRowID').animate({
    'marginTop' : "-=30px" 
    });
});});
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: *`so content can be displayed`* what content? Can you show a HTML example?

Comment: Sorry, I am imagining someone clicking on a table, the row moving up and the content associated with that table being displayed.  That is long term, I  am just trying to get it to move currently.

Comment: If you can setup a quick HTML with a bit of CSS just to see what you're doing?...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reliably animate table elements.
But you can animate a DIV inside a TD

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `<div>` inside a `<td>`*
- Give the `<td>` `colspan="NUMBER OF <TD>s IN A <TR>"` [`<td colspan='3'>`]
- Then assign the div 2 classes:

  1. One class that has styles for the div when it's normally hidden [`.content`]
  2. One class that has styles for the div when it's showing [`.on`]
- Use a method and event to activate the show/hide behavior [`$('.trigger').on("click", ...`]
- Then use `.toggleClass()` method on the class that shows the div [`.toggleClass('on')`]

### Demo

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
  $('.content').toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 3px solid black;
  min-width: 10ch
}

.trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color:red;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s ease;
  text-align: center;
}

.content.on {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: visible;
  transition: .5s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<caption>Click the Red Border</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='trigger' colspan='3'>
        <div class='content'>CONTENT</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`*` as per @Roko C. Buljan's answer