# Collapse expanded html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I took example of `HTML` table and `jQuery` script and I'm trying to change behaviour this combination. Currently table rows are expanded and collapse on `click`. How change this to be collapsed and expand on `click`.

```js
$('.header').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .sign:after {
  content: "+";
  display: inline-block;
}

.header.expand .sign:after {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr class="header expand">
    <th colspan="2">Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header expand">
    <th colspan="2">Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nc8bt9ss/)

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45394442/2813224)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reverse the default state you simply need to remove the `expand` class from the `.header` elements and set `display: none` on the standard `tr` elements. The JS logic is otherwise identical.

```css
tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table-row;
}

tr {
  display: none;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhgcejbd/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to have collapse to expand behavior, hide the rows initially:

```
 $('.header').nextUntil('tr.header').hide();
```

```js
$('.header').nextUntil('tr.header').hide();
$('.header').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .sign:after {
  content: "+";
  display: inline-block;
}

.header.expand .sign:after {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr class="header expand">
    <th colspan="2">Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header expand">
    <th colspan="2">Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that hiding content using JS will often result in a FOUC. It's far better to do it in CSS